# Mongoose ODM, BreezeJS - one model definition

Tags: javascript, mongoose, breeze

is there any "ready to you" solution how to export mongoose models to client side app? If I imagine perfect world, mongoose models would let me define which properties and methods of entity is needed on client side and generates needed classes for client so I can easily use them with BreezeJS for example.

Any idea? Or is it road to hell combine it together? :))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update - As of **v 1.2.7** - we have provided two facilities that will help accomplish tasks like this.

- The Breeze metadata format has been documented and any json object that adheres to this format and is returned from the breeze metadata call will be used to configure breeze's client side metadata.
- The JsonResultsAdapter may be used to reshape or assist with interpreting the result of any web service call so that any results returned by the call can become Breeze entities.

--- Previous post

Please stay tuned, we will be releasing a new version of breeze in the next few days with support for pluggable json adapters that will allow the consumption of any web service.  And since breeze metadata can already be defined for an arbitrary model, you should be able to consume your mongoose models pretty easily. Of course, the devil IS in the details.